# Proactive vs Preemptive

Tags: word-usage

I need to explain the difference between "proactive" and "preemptive" and come up with a sample of the proper context of each word.

Can someone point me to a previous post or give me their thoughts?

Comment: These are completely different words. They may overlap in some areas, but a dictionary could help you understand the differences.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Essentially, the difference between *pre-emptive* and *proactive* seems to be that *pre-emptive* connotes some kind of action that prevents something from occurring, and *proactive* connotes some kind of action intended to provoke a reaction, or some kind initiating action. See these examples and the supplied links for even more examples.

[pre-emptive on the Collins dictionary](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/preemptive?showCookiePolicy=true)

> **Definitions**
> *adjective*
>
> 1. of, involving, or capable of pre-emption
> 2. (bridge) (of a high bid) made to shut out opposition bidding
> 3. (military) designed to reduce or destroy an enemy's attacking strength before it can use it   ⇒ "a pre-emptive strike"
>
> Usage
>
> Another trial of pre-emptive pain relief was slightly more successful for patients undergoing thoracic surgery

[proactive on the Collins dictionary](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/proactive?showCookiePolicy=true)

> **Definitions**
> *adjective*
>
> 1. tending to initiate change rather than reacting to events
> 2. (psychology) of or denoting a mental process that affects a subsequent process
>
> Usage
>
> Effective progress during the traineeship depends very much on the individual taking a proactive approach to work.